# I want to find the most often sequence of symbols from the list of lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, iteration

I want to find the most often sequence of symbols from the list of [lists]

```py
CATEGORIES = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",
              "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J",
              "K","L","M","N","O","P","R","S","T","U",
              "V","W","X","Y","Z"]

KR8877J = [[0.002,0.006,0.004,0.045,0.002,0.017,0.006,0.077,0.001,0.035,0.042,0.005,0.004,0.039,0.001,0.002,0.001,0.008,0.058,0.352,0.002,0.007,0.017,0.004,0.007,0.007,0.007,0.004,0.005,0.009,0.089,0.036,0.053,0.041,0.004],[0.003,0.007,0.005,0.075,0.001,0.020,0.006,0.044,0.002,0.035,0.026,0.004,0.004,0.033,0.001,0.001,0.003,0.008,0.049,0.360,0.002,0.007,0.021,0.005,0.009,0.003,0.008,0.007,0.003,0.014,0.092,0.048,0.058,0.031,0.004],[0.002,0.000,0.025,0.012,0.006,0.002,0.001,0.627,0.006,0.021,0.022,0.008,0.004,0.006,0.004,0.033,0.000,0.006,0.011,0.009,0.002,0.002,0.009,0.000,0.002,0.040,0.007,0.005,0.015,0.000,0.035,0.001,0.008,0.015,0.053],[0.056,0.008,0.023,0.038,0.015,0.007,0.050,0.006,0.412,0.004,0.005,0.027,0.011,0.005,0.021,0.007,0.073,0.024,0.012,0.005,0.013,0.005,0.027,0.003,0.015,0.001,0.005,0.074,0.002,0.022,0.005,0.011,0.002,0.001,0.006],[0.025,0.011,0.025,0.034,0.018,0.027,0.090,0.008,0.258,0.006,0.007,0.026,0.016,0.008,0.026,0.011,0.079,0.030,0.026,0.008,0.018,0.011,0.033,0.003,0.016,0.001,0.003,0.106,0.004,0.021,0.012,0.013,0.003,0.005,0.014],[0.048,0.027,0.019,0.002,0.028,0.002,0.008,0.017,0.041,0.014,0.012,0.022,0.031,0.005,0.045,0.100,0.004,0.031,0.033,0.002,0.029,0.006,0.021,0.032,0.008,0.038,0.317,0.007,0.017,0.004,0.018,0.005,0.003,0.004,0.002],[0.013,0.002,0.002,0.000,0.164,0.001,0.060,0.004,0.006,0.002,0.018,0.003,0.035,0.002,0.008,0.008,0.001,0.008,0.028,0.005,0.383,0.013,0.063,0.010,0.004,0.002,0.014,0.016,0.002,0.005,0.048,0.011,0.028,0.017,0.012]]

KR8877J_1 = [[0.004,some data]]
KR8877J_2 = [[0.002,some data]]
KR8877J_3 = [[somedata]
KR8877J_4 = [[0.006,some data,0.008]]
KR8877J_5 = [[some data]]
KR8877J_6 = [[some data]]

def readable(x):
    tag = []
    for lst in x:
        index = max(enumerate(lst), key=lambda pair: pair[1])[0]
        tag.append(CATEGORIES[index])
    tag.reverse()
    str = tag 
    print(str)
    #print(tag)


for i in (KR8877J, KR8877J_1,KR8877J_2,KR8877J_3,KR8877J_4,KR8877J_5,KR8877J_6): 
    readable(i)
    

def compare_bitwise(a,b): 
    a_set = set(a) 
    b_set = set(b) 
    if (a_set & b_set): 
         return True 
    else: 
        return False


for i in (KR8877J, KR8877J_1,KR8877J_2,KR8877J_3,KR8877J_4,KR8877J_5,KR8877J_6):
    print(compare_bitwise(i, i+=1))
```

Problem with iteration is here: `print(compare_bitwise(i, i+=1))`
I give an example of data only in the first list because all of them are the same expert one which is have output ['K', 'R', '8', '8', 'J', '7', 'J'] instead ['K', 'R', '8', '8', '7', 'J', 'J']

Comment: or maybe I could make it a string? my outputs: ['K', 'R', '8', '8', '7', 'J', 'J']
['K', 'R', '8', '8', '7', 'J', 'J']
['K', 'R', '8', '8', '7', 'J', 'J']
['K', 'R', '8', '8', 'J', '7', 'J']
['K', 'R', '8', '8', '7', 'J', 'J']
['K', 'R', '8', '8', '7', 'J', 'J']

Comment: Could you elaborate "on most often sequence of symbols from list"? A simple example would be great. Ex. How often  a sequence of ["A","B","C"]

Comment: if the issue is with only prinnt then use a variable to store [KR8877J_1,KR8877J_2,KR8877J_3,KR8877J_4,KR8877J_5,KR8877J_6] and fetch using index instead of i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without examples of `some data`, it's hard to tell what's expected. In any case, for the line `print(compare_bitwise(i, i+=1))` - if you're trying to compare each `KR8877J_...` sequence with the next one, so `KR8877J_1` with `KR8877J_2`, `KR8877J_2` with `KR8877J_3`, etc. - then the smallest change would be: Assign that sequence to a list or tuple and then index accordingly.

```py
seq = (KR8877J_1,KR8877J_2,KR8877J_3,KR8877J_4,KR8877J_5,KR8877J_6)
for i in range(len(seq) - 1):
    print(compare_bitwise(seq[i], seq[i+1]))
```

But indexing with `range()` and `len()` isn't isn't good or efficient in Python. Instead, it's better to use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) with `seq` and `seq[1:]`:

```py
seq = (KR8877J_1,KR8877J_2,KR8877J_3,KR8877J_4,KR8877J_5,KR8877J_6)
for i, j in zip(seq, seq[1:]):
    print(compare_bitwise(i, j))
```

---

*Edit:* I don't fully understand what you mean but you can convert the tag list to a tuple using `tag_tup = tuple(tag)` and *`return`* the value from `readable()` instead of just printing it. Or just `return tag`. And then feed that as a key for [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) by doing `counter = collections.Counter()` before looping for `readable(i)` and then `counter.update({tag_tup: 1})` inside loop, along with the `tag_tup`.

```py
def readable(x):
    tag = []
    for lst in x:
        index = max(enumerate(lst), key=lambda pair: pair[1])[0]
        tag.append(CATEGORIES[index])
    tag.reverse()
    print(tag)
    return tag


import collections
counter = collections.Counter()
for i in (KR8877J, KR8877J_1,KR8877J_2,KR8877J_3,KR8877J_4,KR8877J_5,KR8877J_6):
    tag_tup = tuple(readable(i))
    counter.update({tag_tup: 1})

print(counter)
```

See the `collections.Counter` docs (linked above) to then get the [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) combinations.

Comment: Your suggestion for seq is working, thank you! but I still have a problem. because I need to find the most often output which is the result of work - tag list. So I need to find the most often combination of the ['K', 'R', '8', '8', '7', 'J', 'J']
['K', 'R', '8', '8', '7', 'J', 'J']
['K', 'R', '8', '8', '7', 'J', 'J']
['K', 'R', '8', '8', 'J', '7', 'J']
['K', 'R', '8', '8', '7', 'J', 'J'] - so its result of readable function, because 
tag = []     for lst in x: index = max(enumerate(lst), key=lambda pair: pair[1])[0]
 .....
    str = tag 
    print(str)

Comment: See the edit for how you might find the most common tag combinations. Note that if order matters, then **sort** it before you convert it to a tuple.